# three symmetrically placed equal circles

Tags: geometry, circles

[image: Enter image description here[1]]

If three symmetrically placed equal circles intersect in a single point, as illustrated in the figure. What should be the distance between the centre of the three circle for obtaining such a overlap.

Answer (score 1):

Simple geometry:

radius $r=OA=OB=OC=OD=OE=OF$ and $AB=BC=CA=r\sqrt{3}$

[image]

Comment: how do you know OA=OD?

Comment: Firstly, $\Delta ABC$ is an equilateral triangle with centre $O$.  Secondly, $OE$ and $AC$ are mutually perpendicular bisectors.  Hence, $E$ is a mirror image of $O$ about $AC$.

Comment: Also by coordinate geometry, the first circle is
$$(x-a\cos \theta)^2+(y-a\sin \theta)^2=a^2$$
the second circle is
$$[x-a\cos (\theta+120^\circ)]^2+[y-a\sin (\theta+120^\circ)]^2=a^2$$
and the third circle is
$$[x-a\cos (\theta+240^\circ)]^2+[y-a\sin (\theta+240^\circ)]^2=a^2$$

Comment: how do you know AC bisects OE?  how do you know OE is of length $a$?

Comment: Congruent triangles (SSS): same radii (two sets), common sides.

Comment: @Jayen, as in the question, *"symmetrically placed equal circles"* may not be proper wordings in the context of Euclidean geometry, try using CAS to draw the $3$ mentioned circle equations for your interest.

Comment: Chord $OE$ is also known as **radical axis** of two circles.  BTW, $a$ and $r$ refer to same thing.

Answer (score 0):

It is a very easy question. $AB=BC=CA=r\sqrt 3$ where $A,B,C$ are the centers of the circles and $r$ is the radius of the circles.